# Is automatically close the database connection after getting the result in Kohana framework?

Tags: mysql, kohana

I am using Kohana framework. I'm having an issue with my system. The issue is my system is too slow because of too many query connections to server. The maximum query connections set in server is 600. And my system having 500-800 concurrent users. I'm assuming this is caused by the Db connection being opened for the first query call but never closed since the query never ends.Is automatically close the database connection after getting the result in Kohana framework?

Comment: what is your question? Do you want to close the db connection after its use?  if so need to see the php.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: `Database::instance()->disconnect()`

But this shouldn't be a solution.

1. Optimize queries
2. Optimize table (indexes)
3. Change transaction level
4. Optimize MySQL server
5. Don't use ORM to get list of results